# Network problems under dualboot with win 7

Tags: networking, dual-boot, kubuntu

First of all I am very new to Linux so it might be simple problem. I have installed the latest Kubuntu in dualboot with a Windows 7 installation on my workstation at work. For a week or so, the network has been running very well, only using Kubuntu. But after a very brief boot into Windows 7 and back to Kubuntu, Kubuntu has stop being able to connect to the wired connection.

Using ifconfig I will not get an IPV4 address. So I tried

```
sudo dhclient -r
```

followed by a

```
sudo dhclient
```

but when the last command is performed it seems to hang on the command and does not go further.

Booting into Windows and the internet will work.

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Please try here and edit with issues you are having http://www.pcworld.com/article/2455972/how-to-fix-your-internet-connection-in-ubuntu-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described here:
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/internet#TOC-No-wired-or-wireless-internet-on-a-dual-boot-computer

> This may be due to a flaw in Windows, which can be repaired easily.
>
> If you have a dual bootable PC with Windows, and you've just used Windows, you may not get an IP address after a reboot in Linux. And so no internet connection.
>
> This has the following reason: every network card has a unique MAC address. This address is ingrained in your NIC. The DHCP server in your router remembers this MAC address.
>
> When you access the internet in Windows and then reboot in Linux, in many cases you'll get no IP address from the DHCP server in your router. Because this server will recall that it previously issued an IP address for that very same MAC address, and won't issue a new one.
>
> You can solve this by forcing Windows to release the IP address, before you reboot the PC. By the way: Linux by default does release the IP address on shutdown. So a reboot from Linux into Windows causes no problems.
>
> Tip: Did you forget to force Windows to release the IP address, and you don't want to boot Windows to do it as yet? Then simply boot Ubuntu or Linux Mint twice in a row. After the second boot of Ubuntu or Mint you can probably connect.
>
> A. Manual method
>   1. Open a DOS window in Windows
>
> Windows XP:
>   Start - Programs - Accessories - Command Prompt
>
> Windows 7:
>   Start - All Programs - Accessories - Command Prompt
>
> 2. Type:
>      ipconfig /release
>
> (note the space between ipconfig and /release)
>
> And press Enter.
>
> B. Semi-automatic method
>   By means of a shortcut on your desktop, you can apply a semi-automatic solution for this.
>
> 1. Open Notepad
>      Windows XP: Start - Programs - Accessories - Notepad
> 2. type the following text:
>      ipconfig /release
> 3. Save this text file as release.bat and place it on your desktop. Now you can always simply double click this file, before you exit Windows.
>
> As I said, Linux releases the IP address by default on shutdown. So a reboot from Linux into Windows causes no problems.